# Configure true absolute imports in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

```
import foo from '/foo';
```

should import `{sourceRoot}/foo`

where `sourceRoot` is `{pwd}/src`

Is it possible to do this via `tsconfig.json`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding this to tsconfig should work:

```json
    "paths": {
        "/*": [ "./src/*" ]
    },
```

Based on this comment https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/47646#issuecomment-1024456182